# Define DesignWidth with a constant in a XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I would like to define the `DesignWidth` value with a constant but the view it does not seem to have the defined width in Blend.
I have a `Constants.class`

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static int ApplicationWidth { get { return 1280;} }
    public static int ApplicationHeight { get { return 720; } }
}
```

and the `View.xaml`

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:app.Constants"
    d:DesignWidth="{x:Static constants:Constants.ApplicationWidth}">
</UserControl>
```

In Visual Studio the View Width is `267px` and in Blend is `262px`. How can I set the `Width` without hard coding the values in the `XAML` files in order to have the desired size in Blend an Visual Studio ?

Comment: Perhaps the `Contants` class should be static? Just a thought.

Comment: I get the same result with a static Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:app.Constants"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  d:DesignWidth="{Binding Source={x:Static constants:Constants.ApplicationWidth}}">
```