# Constants with multiple static class for Xaml properties

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've generated some constants from images files in our project. However, I'm having trouble accessing multiple static classes as a Xaml property.

`Cannot resolve type "Constants.Images.Icons.IcAccount.Svg". (XFC0000)`

```
namespace Common
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static class Images
        {
            public static class Icons
            {
                public static class IcAccount
                {
                    public static readonly string Svg = "res:images.icons.ic_account";
                    public static readonly string File = "ic_account.svg";
                }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
  x:Class="myapp.Pages.ActiveBookingPage"
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:control="clr-namespace:myapp.Controls;assembly=myapp"
  xmlns:common="clr-namespace:myapp.Common;assembly=myapp">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <control:CustomImageButton
            ButtonImage="{x:Static common:Constants.Images.Icons.IcAccount.Svg}"
```

I've tried several variations however I can't specify any more than `{x:Static common:Constants.Svg}`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207672/define-designwidth-with-a-constant-in-a-xaml-file) as an initial basis, but it doesn't use multiple classes.

I’d be happy to change the format of my constants class.

Comment: common:Constants.Images.Icons.IcAccount.Svg, it is going to consider images as property, so icons and so on, try using converter.

Comment: @Prayag can you exand on how I could use a converter with constants ? I'd be fine with changing the structure of the constants file too.

Comment: At first, nested classes are so smelly, you should find how to refactor your code and simplify it. In second place, you should do the fields as properties. And finally, try `{x:Static (common:Constants.Images.Icons.IcAccount).Svg}`. I'm not sure if parens should include `common:`, try both options. I don't remember so well how wpf works

Comment: @DrkDeveloper thanks for your help... unfortunetly variations around the parens hasn't worked...

Comment: @Jules oh, oh, oh, I think I remember! `common:Constants+Images+Icons+IcAccount.Svg` (compiler nested classes name stuff)

Comment: @DrkDeveloper Yes that does build... just need to get my project running to see...

Comment: @DrkDeveloper Awsome! it works..Add your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does some clever stuff to manage nested classes, renaming it with the full class-tree with "+".

Use

```
common:Constants+Images+Icons+IcAccount.Svg
```

Comment: Thanks! Had some issues to get the project running, but works perfectly... thanks so much !!!